# how to search for specific whole words within a string , via SQL, compatible with both HIVE/IMPALA

Tags: sql, regex, hive, impala, rlike

I need to search a column(varchar) for specific whole words. I'm using the query below but not getting the desired results;

```
    select *
    from table1
    WHERE upper(c.name) RLIKE ('FECHADO|CIERRE|CLOSED|REVISTO. NORMAL.')
```

My problem is to guarantee that, for example with the word 'CLOSED', that only matches; 'Case Closed', but not 'Case Dis**closed**'. The query above can't match whole words only.
Can anyone help me to find the best way to achieve those results, both in HIVE an IMPALA.

My best regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HIVE/PIG JOIN Based on SUBSTRING match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70010173/hive-pig-join-based-on-substring-match)

Comment: Thank's Matt, but unfortunately no. The instr function does not distinguish 'Closed' from 'Disclosed'. instr(column, 'Closed') finds both. Thank you anyway.

Comment: What REVISTO. NORMAL. should match? word REVISTO, dot, space, NORMAL dot ??? or something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add word boundary `\\b` to match only exact words:

```
rlike '(?i)\\bFECHADO\\b|\\bCIERRE\\b|\\bCLOSED\\b'
```

`(?i)` means case insensitive, no need to use UPPER.

And the last alternative in your regex pattern is `REVISTO. NORMAL.`

If dots in it should be literally dots, use `\\.`

Like this: `REVISTO\\. NORMAL\\.`

Dot in regexp means any character and should be shielded with two backslashes to match dot literally.

Above regex works in Hive. Unfortunately I have no Impala to test it

Comment: Thank you very much. I will test on impala to check if it runs OK.

Comment: In your opinion it is better to use (rlike) or (regexp)?

Comment: @LEOPOLDO these two relational operators are synonyms in Hive, see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/languagemanual+udf#LanguageManualUDF-RelationalOperators

Comment: @LEOPOLDO In Impala regexp and rlike are also synonyms

Comment: Many thanks leftjoin. This worked. The only comment I need to add is regarding the '\\.' for literally dots in 'REVISTO\\. NORMAL\\.'. I've tested and works likewise without them; like this:  where c.name rlike ('(?i)REVISTO. NORMAL.')

Comment: @LEOPOLDO Dot means any character. Check, it will match not only dots, it will match REVISTOX, REVISTOY,  REVISTO. etc etc

Comment: Ok. You're 100% right. Thank you and my best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I explained a similar solution here: [HIVE/PIG JOIN Based on SUBSTRING match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70010173/hive-pig-join-based-on-substring-match/70022996#70022996)
This will make a lot of records and take a long time to run but I think it will run better than running a like as it uses a join to complete the matching instead of searching all records.

If this is a hive only solution I would explode on " " with lateral view and then match on closed.

1. split - makes an array based on splitting on " "
2. LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE - changes an array into rows.

   ```
   WITH (
       select *
       from table1
       LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(SPLIT( name, " ")) table_name as names
   ) as exploded_names

   select * from exploded_names
       where 
          names IN ('FECHADO','CIERRE','CLOSED','REVISTO.')
   ```

Comment: Hi Matt. Let me test. But I think that could be more appropriate to use a regexp. thank you in advance, i'l test it

Comment: If the data set is small, reexp could work just fine.  The issue I see is that you are comparing every record in the entire data set.  This is expensive.  Doing this join allows you to spread the load to a join and that makes it more efficient.